# How to read multiple forms of attributes of function?

Tags: python, polynomials

I need to load attributes for my Polynomial function, but it's load in a different form.

In the assignment, I have 3 forms values and I don't know how to read all of them. One of them is entered as list(), next one as elements and the last one is entered by a number of degrees of the polynomial (this is the greatest problem for me).

```py
p1 = Polynomial([1,-3,0,2])
p2 = Polynomial(1,-3,0,2)
p3 = Polynomial(x0=1,x3=2,x1=-3)
>>> print(*p*)
2x^3 - 3x + 1
```

I already tried somethink like:

```py
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self,*X):
        self.x = X
    def __str__(self):
        index = 0
        while True:
            element = element+self.x[index]+"x^"+index
```

but thats don't expected the 3rd case and doesn't work with 1st and 2nd.

Comment: use keyword arguments for the third case `def  __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):` the kwargs is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
```

In the first case, `args` will contain `[[1,-3,0,2]]` (so you want to manipulate `args[0]`)

In the second case, `args` will contain `[1,-3,0,2]`

And in the last case, `kwargs` will contain `{ x0: 1, x3: 2, x1: -3 }`

In that last case, to translate `kwargs` into the list you want (IE `[1,-3,0,2]`), you can do

```py
[kwargs.get("x0", 0), kwargs.get("x1", 0), kwargs.get("x2", 0), kwargs.get("x3", 0)]
```

This will give you a list of the values of `kwargs` you want at the right keys, or 0 if not found. (nicer way : `[kwargs.get(x, 0) for x in ["x0","x1","x2","x3"]]`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution, but I have one more question, how could I make from { x0: 1, x3: 2, x1: -3 } to [1,-3,0,2] ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to define your class constructor as specified, you need it to be able to sort between list and multiple elements when args are given, or multiple keyword arguments when **kwargs are given.

Assuming user doesn't screw up input, this would be a working example :

```
class Polynomial:
    """
    Assuming max. degree is always 3
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) == 1:  # here user gave a list
                self.x0 = args[0][0]
                self.x1 = args[0][1]
                self.x2 = args[0][2]
                self.x3 = args[0][3]
            elif len(args) == 4:  # here we have the four coefficients
                self.x0 = args[0]
                self.x1 = args[1]
                self.x2 = args[2]
                self.x3 = args[3]
        elif kwargs: # if args are not present, we check if keywords arguments are
            self.x0 = kwargs['x0']
            self.x1 = kwargs['x1']
            self.x2 = kwargs['x2']
            self.x3 = kwargs['x3']
```

Here is a tutorial about argument handling : https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Now you can modify it so you take into account multiple degree, absent keywords, input mistakes etc...
Sometimes, input checking and cleaning can be complex enough so it takes a whole other method definition.